# How to know how many times a QR code has been scanned

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I've been working on a QR code that sends the person who scans it to a user's profile on a website, how can I know how many times the QR code, which is made with python, has been scanned and how can I show that on the website?

Comment: The URL needs to be unique to the QR code somehow (maybe adding `?source=qr` or something?) and then you can count the number of times that unique URL is loaded server-side.